# Internal Sever Error when using aws cognito from asp.net core webapi

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-webapi

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> AmazonServiceException: Unable to get IAM security credentials from
>   EC2 Instance Metadata Service.
>   Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.FetchCredentials()
>   in DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.cs, line 154

Comment: Please enter a example of your code to better explain your case and so that we can help you.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error implies that you have not set up credentials properly for making AWS SigV4 API calls. I implore you to read the following [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config.html) and verify that your SDK set up is correct.

You could make some sample S3/EC2 API calls to validate the setup.